# PHP GET after htaccsess rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get the variable from my url but having problems.

the default URL is  `http://localhost/category.php?category_slug=gaming`

With my htaccsess file

```
RewriteRule ^category/([\w\d-]+)$ /category.php?category_slug=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category_slug=([\w\d-]+)
RewriteRule ^category$ %1 [R,L]
```

I get my desired URL `http://localhost/category/gaming`

but now I am needing to get the page variable from the url `http://localhost/category/gaming?page=2`

in category.php i have `$page=$_GET['page']`;

but when I echo it out i get `Warning: Undefined array key "page" in F:\Server\htdocs\category.php on line 5`

The closest i can get is with the following code

```
RewriteRule ^category/([\w\d-]+)$ /category.php?category_slug=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category_slug=([\w\d-]+)
RewriteRule ^category$ %1 [R,L]
```

I get no errors but the data isnt showing

The desired URL would be either
`http://localhost/category/gaming?page=2` or `http://localhost/category/gaming/page2/`

im pretty sure my lack of knowledge of editing my htaccsess file is to blame. and need someone to point me in the right direction please

Comment: Change `[R,L]` to `[R,L,QSA]` where `QSA` stands for "Query String Append".

Comment: You need to add the [QSA] rewrite flag: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/RewriteFlags+QSA

Comment: It's not required on the _redirect_, only the rewrite (first directive). @Sammitch

Comment: @MrWhite ah, yes. I didn't read the rules themselves particularly closely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^category/([\w\d-]+)$ /category.php?category_slug=$1 [L]
> ```

You need to add the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag to the first rule that rewrites the request. This appends/merges the query string on the request (ie. `page=2`) with the query string you are including in the *substitution* string (ie. `category_slug`), otherwise the query string in the *substitution* replaces the query string on the request.

(If, however, you are *not* including a query string in the *substitution* string then the original query string on the request is passed through by default - no need for the `QSA` flag in this case.)

Minor point, but the `\w` shorthand class already includes digits, so the `\d` is superfluous.

You should also make sure that MultiViews is disabled, otherwise all query string parameters will be lost.

For example:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)$ /category.php?category_slug=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This then handles both `/category/gaming` and `/category/gaming?page=2`.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category_slug=([\w\d-]+)
> RewriteRule ^category$ %1 [R,L]
> ```

Your second rule isn't actually doing anything, unless this is related to something else. This would likely result in a malformed redirect if it did anything at all?

This rule would redirect a URL of the form `/category?category_slug=gaming` to `gaming` (only) - which is dependent on you having a `RewriteBase` defined. Is that the intention?

Comment: thank you so much for helping. and no the second rule is not needed. so i have now removed it.